# opening implicit cursor with for loop

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have a stored procedure that has following pl/sql block. This block was using select query in for statement but i need to change that static variable to dynamic query. As I changed that it has error. Is there any way to use variable with FOR LOOP in implicit cursor.

```
  declare
      sql_query varchar2(32767) := 'select ctlchar ';
      kpiNameQuery varchar2(600);
      isWg boolean := true;
    begin
          IF isWG then
             kpiNameQuery := 'select distinct KPI_NAME from weeklykpi where kpi_name in (select kpi_wg from auxillary.kpi_types) order by 1';

      Else
        kpiNameQuery := 'select distinct KPI_NAME from weeklykpi where kpi_name in (select kpi_wg1 from auxillary.kpi_types) order by 1';
      End IF;         

     for KPI_NAME in kpiNameQuery
      loop
          sql_query := sql_query || ' , min(case when KPI_NAME = '''||x.KPI_NAME||''' then KPI_VALUE end) as '||x.KPI_NAME;
          dbms_output.put_line(sql_query);
      end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve similar functionality with the following using cursor

```
declare
      type t_cursor is ref cursor;
      c_cursor t_cursor;
      l_sql varchar2(512);
      l_var number;
   begin
     l_sql := 'select count(*) from emp';  -- do dynamic check before here for    
   -- correct sql
     open c_cursor for l_sql;
     loop
       fetch c_cursor 
        into l_var;           
       exit When c_cursor%notfound;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('val '||l_var);           
     end loop;  
     close c_cursor;
  end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfotunately no, [the doc states](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#i13057):

> If the dynamic SQL statement is a SELECT statement that returns multiple rows, native dynamic SQL gives you these choices:
>
> - Use the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement with the BULK COLLECT INTO clause.
> - Use the OPEN FOR, FETCH, and CLOSE statements.

So you will have to use a REF cursor (or `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` and loop over the results).

Incidentally, in your case you could go for static SQL and have comparable performance:

```
BEGIN
   FOR cc IN (SELECT DISTINCT KPI_NAME
                FROM weeklykpi
               WHERE kpi_name IN (SELECT CASE WHEN l_variable = 1
                                                  THEN kpi_wg
                                              ELSE kpi_wg1
                                         END
                                    FROM auxillary.kpi_types) LOOP
               ORDER BY 1
      -- do something
   END LOOP;
END;
```

You'll have to use some other type than boolean though since it's unknown to SQL.

Comment: very much thank you ! well i ended up using explicit cursor but the tenchnique you told is nice. thank you for more information!